# How to add columns after unpivoting in Power Bi?

Tags: powerbi-desktop, unpivot

I have a dataset with data separated by month in every column. I selected "**unpivot all other columns**" and selected the fields before the month columns. So now I have my data aggregated by all the months in one column and all the values in another column. Problem is that every month, I need to add a new column. I clicked refresh data, and the new column does not appear. Looking in the Advanced Editor, it shows the file having 70 columns, when it should be 71. I'm not sure why it's not even reading the new column.

Sample Data (Before)
Jan 21 Feb 21 Mar 21 Apr 21

Sample Data (After)
Month   Value
Jan 21
Feb 21
Mar 21
Apr 21

Problem arises when I add May - refresh the data, I do not see it in the Month column.

I'm not sure if it's because I add a custom column after unpivoting the other ones (non-month columns). This custom column is to change the format of the newly created "Month" column to date in MM-DD-YY format.

#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Columns", [insert non-month columns here]

#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Date", each Date.FromText("01/" & Text.Start([Month],3) & "/20" & Text.End([Month],2))),

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data and expected output [How To](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow)

Comment: @smpa01 let me know if my edit makes more sense now